# Как в инсталяционном скрипте setup.py написать загрузку exe-файла из BitBucket-репозитария?

Tags: python

Привет,

Пишу setup.py для моего Python-пакета. Применяю python 3.4 и setuptools, т.к. в офиц. документации сказано что distutils теперь legacy.

Мой пакет применяет консольную программу mytools.exe. При установке пакета мне нужно чтобы скачивалась последняя версия этой консольной программы.

В офиц. документации по setuptools не наблюдаю каких-либо параметров позволяющих указать custom-функцию в которой я бы мог написать загрузку mytools.exe.

Существуют ли стандартные способы решающие мою задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `dependency_links`. Этот механизм предназначен для скачивания и установки файлов, которые не являются модулями Python.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # ...
    dependency_links = [
        "http://server.with.your.file.com/download/mytools.exe",
    ],
)
```

Подробнее:

- [Building and Distributing Packages with Setuptools — Dependencies that aren’t in PyPI](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi)

Comment: Вот за это спасибо! А можно ли указать папку, куда сохранять тулзу? Если, да, то можете поправить свой ответ? Пока не вижу способа, т.к. dependency_links это список

Comment: @sys_dev: нет, насколько я знаю нельзя указать